# Using scanner.nextInt() to get 2 integers from multiple lines

Tags: java, console-application, user-input

I have the following code where I am trying to get pairs of two numbers and store them in a 2D list.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numEdges; i++) {
        int x = input.nextInt();
        int y = input.nextInt();
        edges.add(new int[]{x, y});
        System.out.println("x-y: " + x + " " + y);
    }
```

My code is supposed to accept all input at once in the format below where the first two inputs are used elsewhere.

My issue is coming from the sets of pairs in the third line where my for loop is waiting for the
enter key to be pressed before completing its last cycle.

```
5
5
2 3
3 4
1 2
0 2
2 4
```

The console output after this code looks like this

```
x-y: 2 3
x-y: 3 4
x-y: 1 2
x-y: 0 2
            //Pauses here on last iteration until enter key pressed
x-y: 2 4    //Then finishes normally
```

I've included a screenshot below that shows where the code is waiting for the enter key.

I'm sure this is a mistake that lies in some misunderstanding of how `nextInt()` works but this is also my first time working with input of this format.

[image: Screenshot of the console output]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Yup, java can't process that until a newline is pressed in the first place. Nothing you can do about it. Note that if this input came in directly, e.g. via `java yourapp.Main <data`, it would work fine.